# Gradle can not find 'lint' as dependency for custom task

Tags: android, android-studio, build, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to create a simple, easy-to-use Gradle task that runs everything I expect the continuous integration server to run. For now, my app/build.gradle file contains the following code (rest omitted):

```
task continuousIntegrationDebug(dependsOn: [assembleDebug, lint, runCheckstyle, runPmd, runFindbugs]) {
}
```

Sadly, Gradle complains that it can not find lint (same for lintDebug and lintRelease):

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find property 'lint' on project ':app'.
```

Interestingly, the following line works when I run a check:

```
check.dependsOn 'lint'
```

And the following external call works, too (from project root):

```
./gradlew app:lint
```

What did I forget? I am using version `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0` and the latest versions of build tools etc.

Also, I had to run pmd, checkstyle and findbugs externally first before I could run the task itself (were not installed before). How can I ensure they always get downloaded the first time the Gradle files get synced in Android Studio?

Comment: My guess is that dependsOn in the way you defined it does not expect an array, thus tries to treat lint as a property which does not exist, rather than another task. Can you try removing the square brackets, i.e. change the code to `dependsOn: assembleDebug, lint, runCheckstyle, runPmd, runFindbugs`?

Comment: I already tried running the command without lint - that works. Also, I tried the `task.dependsOn otherTask` syntax with lint, which does not work either. I also tried without the array - which gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather a hint than a working solution, but it might point you into the right direction.

I've checked the internal Groovy code which adds the lint task [1]. They do something like:

```
 lint = project.tasks.create("lint", Lint)
```

... in order to define the Lint task. So maybe you need to create the lint task yourself first?

Another solution I stumbled upon is pointed out in [2]:

```
def compileLintTask = project.tasks.find {it.name == 'compileLint'}
    compileLintTask.dependsOn(copyLintJar)
```

There `tasks.find` is used in order to find the compileLint task. Maybe you can find the task you are looking for in the same way?

1. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/BasePlugin.groovy
2. https://engineering.linkedin.com/android/writing-custom-lint-checks-gradle

Comment: I did not get it to run the way you described, but I had another idea when I had a look at line 232 in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/BasePlugin.groovy#232 - the task 'check' depends on 'lint' and is available from the outside. Therefore, if I change the part of my code to `dependsOn: [assembleDebug, check, runCheckstyle, runPmd, runFindbugs]` I get a functional Lint check after compilation. :)

Comment: Great. But please keep in mind that `check` is like an anchor task where other tools, like findbugs for instance, hook in [1]. So by depending on `check` a couple of other tasks might be executed as well. 1. http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-General-Tasks

Comment: That's definitely right - and it's why I wrote a comment instead of an answer. ;) If I can find a better solution I will post it here.